# Swift PHP file upload with parameters

Tags: php, ios, swift, parameter-passing

I’ve been working on an App where you can take a picture and then it is send to a server via PHP (POST). Everything works fine, I get the picture. But now I was thinking that it would be better if you can show the name of the user that took the picture. The problem is, I don’t know how to send parameters from this Function to the PHP $_POST. I tried using request.httpBody but when I run the PHP file it says there is no value in the variable. My code looks like the following:

```
func subirFotoRequest(){
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.155/BolsaTrabajo/imagen.php")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let postString = "username\(userName)&userlastname\(lastName)"
//Where userName and lastName are global variables declared before//

let request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

if (imageView.image == nil)
{
    return
}

let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)

if(image_data == nil)
{
    return
}

let body = NSMutableData()
indicadorActividad.startAnimating()

let fname = "test.png"
let mimetype = "image/png"


body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append(image_data!)
body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

request.httpBody = body as Data
let session = URLSession.shared

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {            (
    data, response, error) in

    guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    print(dataString)
    //self.indicadorActividad.stopAnimating()



    do {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.indicadorActividad.stopAnimating()

        self.imageView.image = nil;
        });
    }
    catch{
        //Errores
    }


   }
   task.resume()       
  }    

func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

example to put userID:

```
body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"userID\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("{value of userID}\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

**Origin**

Your code use `form-data` to post value.

```
body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

Above code generate post value `hi` for key `test`.
Just put your username... like this.

Comment: Hi Codus, first of all thank you for taking your time for answering. Could you please explain me this a bit further?(Hi as key for test)  For example, if I want to add another parameter, should I put another line like "Hi" and just replace it with, let's say, userID?

Comment: As you see the code above, `--\(boundary)\r\nContent-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\nhi\r\n` put the parameter exactly. I can get value(`hi`) of `$_POST["test"]` .

Comment: Oh I see, so if I want to call a $_Post['ID'] the code would look like... --\(boundary)\r\nContent-Disposition:form-data; name=\"Id\"\r\n\r\nId\r\n  correct?

Comment: Thanks for the Code-Update, I'm starting to see it clearly now

Comment: Yes, note the case difference `ID` and `Id` :)

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableURLRequest` (or `URLRequest`) cannot have multiple `httpBody`s. (And HTTP protocol cannot send multiple bodies in a single request.)

So, remove these lines:

```
    let postString = "username\(userName)&userlastname\(lastName)"
    //Where userName and lastName are global variables declared before//

    let request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

(The latter line must be causing compile-time error, but that's another thing.)

And replace the lines assigning `httpBody` later:

```
    //### Use `Data` rather than `NSMutableData` in Swift.
    var body = Data()
    indicadorActividad.startAnimating()

    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    //### Assuming `userName` and `lastName` are non-Optional.
    body.append("\(userName)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"userlastname\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("\(lastName)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    //### No need to cast, when you use `Data`.
    request.httpBody = body
```

When you want to send text parameters in addition to image, you add other *part* s in *multipart* like `"test"` in your code. (Oh, it's already shown in Codus' answer.)

---

This is not mandatory to make your code work, but your code made more Swift-ish would be:

```
func subirFotoRequest() {
    //### If you eventually need forced-upwrapping, do it as soon as possible!
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.155/BolsaTrabajo/imagen.php")!

    //### Use `URLRequest` rather than `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift.
    //### Please do not miss, it's `var` not `let`.
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    //### Consider using `guard` for early-return pattern.
    guard let image = imageView.image else {
        //### Silently ignoring unusual case may not be good for debugging.
        print("imageView.image == nil")
        return
    }

    //### (same as above)
    guard let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
        print("UIImagePNGRepresentation returned nil")
        return
    }

    //### Use `Data` rather than `NSMutableData` in Swift.
    var body = Data()
    indicadorActividad.startAnimating()

    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    //### Assuming `userName` and `lastName` are non-Optional.
    body.append("\(userName)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"userlastname\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("\(lastName)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    //### No need to cast, when you use `Data`.
    request.httpBody = body

    //### No need to cast, when you use `URLRequest`.
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, response != nil, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        //### Use `String` rather than `NSString` in Swift.
        let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        //### Supplying default value prevents output "Optional(...)".
        print(dataString ?? "Undecodable result")

        //### No code throws here.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.indicadorActividad.stopAnimating()

            self.imageView.image = nil
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making more "Swifty" my code, I will edit it, make some changes and add more in the "multipart" area like you and Codus said